# AttributeError creating line plot using matplotlib

Tags: pandas, loops, plot

I need to plot in a loop structure each unique "plant_name" in the data below so that the values in "Adj_Prod" are plotted over each other by month for each site. My data in df1 looks like this:

```
    plant_name  month   Adj_Prod    Adj_Prod    Adj_Prod    Adj_Prod    Adj_Prod
0   BIRCH BAY        1  64268.0     64268.0     64268.0     64268.0     64268.0
1   BIRCH BAY        2  131415.5    131415.5    131415.5    131415.5    131415.5
2   BIRCH BAY        3  210202.2    210202.2    210202.2    210202.2    210202.2
3   BIRCH BAY        4  317149.1    317149.1    317149.1    317149.1    317149.1
4   BIRCH BAY        5  432973.8    432973.8    432973.8    432973.8    432973.8
5   BIRCH BAY        6  512809.3    512809.3    512809.3    512809.3    512809.3
6   BIRCH BAY        7  607973.6    607973.6    607973.6    607973.6    607973.6
7   BIRCH BAY        8  687322.8    667062.4    682211.8    680210.6    672797.5
8   BIRCH BAY        9  724324.4    692311.0    726442.7    723927.7    720320.0
9   BIRCH BAY       10  778997.5    764772.8    792752.3    792855.2    788970.0
10  BIRCH BAY       11  833594.9    843887.2    871843.0    874795.6    843567.4
11  BIRCH BAY       12  893822.2    916116.3    927657.8    942680.9    917816.7
12  BARON CHAPEL    1   34218.1      34218.1     34218.1     34218.1     34218.1
13  BARON CHAPEL    2   70853.1      70853.1     70853.1     70853.1     70853.1
14  BARON CHAPEL    3   111367.1    111367.1    111367.1    111367.1    111367.1
15  BARON CHAPEL    4   161482.2    161482.2    161482.2    161482.2    161482.2
16  BARON CHAPEL    5   209338.5    209338.5    209338.5    209338.5    209338.5
17  BARON CHAPEL    6   241771.9    241771.9    241771.9    241771.9    241771.9
18  BARON CHAPEL    7   267183.3    267183.3    267183.3    267183.3    267183.3
19  BARON CHAPEL    8   291989.0    290321.0    294038.6    281854.5    288645.7
20  BARON CHAPEL    9   314834.0    322328.5    318351.3    304571.9    310119.9
21  BARON CHAPEL    10  348497.7    358994.8    349025.9    340384.3    343494.6
22  BARON CHAPEL    11  381433.1    391930.2    383084.3    377981.7    375497.5
23  BARON CHAPEL    12  416721.8    435259.4    415697.2    412921.0    404511.5
```

I need to make 2 plots in this case that should plot the "Adj_Prod" by month for each site. Thank you since I am stll learning python from matlab.

```
import matplotlib.patches
levels, categories = pd.factorize(df1['month'])
colors = [plt.cm.prism(i) for i in levels] 
handles = [matplotlib.patches.Patch(color=plt.cm.prism(i), label=c) for i, c in enumerate(categories)]
sites = (df1.plant_name.unique())
sites = sites.tolist()
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,4))
for i in range(len(sites)):
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(df1.loc[df1['plant_name']==sites[i]].Adj_Prod, df1.loc[df1['plant_name']==sites[i]].month,edgecolors=colors,marker='o',facecolors='none')
    site = str(sites[i])
    plt.title(site + (' ') + ('Region') + (' Wind Production ') + str(df1.columns[0])  )
    plt.xlabel('Month'); plt.ylabel('Estimated Production')
    plt.legend(handles=handles, title="Year",loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1,0.5),edgecolor='black')
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

I have tried this but I keep getting an attribute error:

```py
AttributeError: 'Line2D' object has no property 'edgecolors'
```

Comment: when asking a question about an error, please always be sure to post the [full traceback](//realpython.com/python-traceback). it includes lots of valuable debugging information. I highly recommend reading the article I linked to closely - learning how to read a traceback is a very important python skill!

Answer (score 1):

The error you are seeing is being raised by this line (I've reformatted for clarity but it's the same code as yours):

```py
    for i in range(len(sites)):
        plt.figure()
-->     plt.plot(
            df1.loc[df1['plant_name']==sites[i]].Adj_Prod, 
            df1.loc[df1['plant_name']==sites[i]].month,
            edgecolors=colors,
            marker='o',
            facecolors='none',
        )
```

The error is this:

```py
AttributeError: 'Line2D' object has no property 'edgecolors'
```

What this is saying is that the function [`matplotlib.pyplot.plot`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html) can't accept the argument `edgecolors`. This type of error comes up any time you call a matplotlib plotting function with the wrong arguments. Matplotlib error tracebacks can be a bit tricky because there are tons of internal calls which are made as part of creating and rendering a figure; checking to make sure your arguments are all allowed is a great first step in plotting.

when you call `plt.plot`, you're creating a line plot. If you look down the list of arguments, there are only a couple color-related arguments you could pass in. Subsetting from the docs I linked to above:

> **`**kwargs`**: ***`Line2D`* properties, optional**
>
> kwargs are used to specify properties like a line label (for auto legends), linewidth, antialiasing, marker face color. Example:
>
> ```py
> plot([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], 'go-', label='line 1', linewidth=2)
> plot([1, 2, 3], [1, 4, 9], 'rs', label='line 2')
> ```
>
> If you specify multiple lines with one plot call, the kwargs apply to all those lines. In case the label object is iterable, each element is used as labels for each set of data.
>
> Here is a list of available Line2D properties:
>
> | Property | Description |
> | --- | --- |
> | color or c | color |
> | markeredgecolor or mec | color |
> | markerfacecolor or mfc | color |
> | markerfacecoloralt or mfcalt | color |

So you can only use the above keyword arguments to specify colors for lines, marker edges, or marker face colors.